# Need C++ (in windows) code to implement HTTP POSTs

Tags: c++, http, post

I am making a windows program that

1. polls a server every 5 seconds and (normally) gets an acknowledgement by POST (there are custom messages)
2. executes alternate code (a packet loggger in this case) when the replies dont come
3. uploads a file to the server by POST when the link is back up.

Please recommend a good **C++ library** that provides HTTP client functionality as **well as a newb-friendly environment (easy debugging)** for developing it. Visual C++, minGW?

I am a newb with programming and a first-time poster here. Google confused me but it led me to **libCURL**. Pardon me for unclear language or scope.

Answer (score 2):

Look up WinInet. It's the Windows API's native HTTP client, with POST capability among others. Libcurl is portable, but it's not technically a part of Windows, you have to link/ship it with the software.